# Question on an example about flatness in Hartshorne

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I have been having trouble understanding some statements regarding flatness in Hartshorne -  in particular relating to some of the examples in the text. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is the issue:

- In example III.9.8.4 Hartshorne discusses an example of a family of twisted cubics arising from the projection of $\mathbb{P}^3$ to $\mathbb{P}^2$ from a point. The result is that the flat limit of the twisted cubic is not only singular, but it has an embedded point at the singular point.
- In example III.9.10.1 he explains why if one takes the reduced induced structure on the fibers, then the family is not flat.

My question is: If one takes the flat family $Y\to\mathbb{A}^1$ from the first bullet, and uses the canonical map $Y_{red}\to Y$, then by composing one gets a family $Y_{red}\to \mathbb{A}^1$, which should be flat by proposition III.9.7 (which states that you have flatness over a smooth curve if every associated point of $Y$ maps to the generic point of the curve). Now, I expected $Y_{red}$ to be the family in the second bullet, but since it is not flat, this cannot be the case. What is going on?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem lies in the sentence beginning "Now, I expected..."  Taking the underlying reduced scheme is not the same thing as replacing the *fibers* by their nilreductions.  There are lots of maps of reduced schemes with non-reduced fibers.  Maybe try to write down a simple example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Enrique, I think what's happening is that $Y$ does not have an embedded point, only its special fiber does. Taking $Y_{\mathrm red}$ does not change anything.

Answer (score 3):

Sandor is right. 
Indeed, in Hartshorne's example the total family $Y$ is defined by the ideal

$$I=(a^2(x+1)-z^2, ax(x+1)-yz, xz-ay, y^2-x^2(x+1)) \subset k[a, x,y,z],$$
whereas the central fibre (corresponding to $a=0$) is defined by

$$I_0 = ( z^2, yz, xz, y^2-x^2(x+1)) \subset k[x,y,z].$$

The following Macauley2 script shows that

- $I$ is a radical ideal, hence $Y$ is a reduced affine scheme, that is $Y=Y_{red}$.
- $I_0$ is *not* radical. In fact, the central fiber  $Y_0$ has an embedded point at the node $(0,0,0)$ corresponding to the nilpotent element $z$.

  `i1 : k=ZZ/32003;`

  `i2 : S=k[a,x,y,z];`

  `i3 : I=ideal (a^2*(x+1)-z^2, a*x*(x+1)-y*z, x*z-a*y, y^2-x^2*(x+1));`

  `o3 : Ideal of S`

  `i4 : I==radical I`

  `o4 = true`

  `i5 : T=k[x,y,z];`

  `i6 : I0=ideal (z^2, y*z, x*z, y^2-x^2*(x+1));`

  `o6 : Ideal of T`

  `i7 : I0 == radical I0`

  `o7 = false`

Comment: You can see the same issue looking at the solutions of $y^2=t^2$ as $t$ varies. The total space is a reduced union of two lines, most fibers are two points, and one fiber is a double point. This is a case where the central fiber is again S1, which Hartshorne's example shows may fail.

Comment: And thank you for the example on the lines too!